# Сайт не видит скрипты

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Всем привет.
Возможно, я что-то не понимаю, прошу подсказать.
В коде пишу `href="../wp-content/themes/site/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"`
Сайт подтягивает и находит файл, если ссылка сайта в адресной строке site.com/page
Но если в адресной строке site.com/page/subpage, то href не работает и консоль выдает ошибки. Подскажите, что не понимаю?)

Comment: почему не так `wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

".." означают родительскую директорию, соответственно в каталоге page нет скриптов. Указывайте ссылку от корня сайта

```
href="/wp-content/themes/site/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

Answer (score 1):

> Люди в [MaxCDN](https://www.maxcdn.com/) любезно предоставляют поддержку CDN для CSS и JavaScript для Bootstrap. Просто используйте эти ссылки [CDN Bootstrap](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/).

Вы можете указать URL:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```